# Close Bootstrap popover within actual popover?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, button, popover

I am using a Twitter Bootstrap popover for a kind of alert confirmation for deleting specific table rows, and can't seem to get the buttons within the popover to affect anything. I have copied the exact "Cancel" button outside the popover and it works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/UK7BE/1/

**HTML**

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash icon-set delLtBlue delPop" title='Delete' 
          data-content="
            <div style='font-size: 14px; color: #000000; font-weight:bold'>
              <span class='icon-warning-2'></span>&nbsp;Are you sure you want to delete the selected row?<br/><br/>
            </div>  
            <input type='button' value='Cancel' class='greenBtn cancelPop' />&nbsp;<input type='button' value='Delete' class='greenBtn' id='delete' />
          " title="Delete"></span>&nbsp;
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.delPop').popover({
              placement:'bottom',
              html : true,
          });
          $("input[type=button].cancelPop").on('click',function(){
            $(".delPop").popover('hide');
          });
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is that when you use bootstrap popover with html content it actually clones the content in `data-content` inside the popover div. So it means that event registered o the original cancel doesn't apply in the new cancel button created in the popover, since this `data-content`'s content is just attribute values and not real element in DOM. So you can use event delegation to bind the click event to document (since it is at the root level) to have it delegated the cancel button.

```
$(document).on('click',"input[type=button].cancelPop", function () {
    $(".delPop").popover('hide');
});
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RnYND/)**

But hold on. You don't need to place the popover content this way. You can instead place the html as is on the page hiding them.

Better yet: separate you popover content to a different hidden element rather than placing the whole html in an attribute.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash icon-set delLtBlue delPop" title='Delete'></span> &nbsp;
<div class="popOverContent">
    <div style='font-size: 14px; color: #000000; font-weight:bold'>
<span class='icon-warning-2'></span>&nbsp;Are you sure you want to delete the selected row?
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <input type='button' value='Cancel' class='greenBtn cancelPop' />&nbsp;
    <input type='button' value='Delete' class='greenBtn' id='delete' />
</div>
```

and apply:

```
$(function () {
     $(document).on('click', "input[type=button].cancelPop", function () {
        $(".delPop").popover('hide');
    });

    $('.delPop').popover({
        placement: 'bottom',
        html: true,
        content: function () {
            return $('.popOverContent').html();
        }
    });

});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RQzBp/)**

Comment: @triplethreat77 You are welcome. By the way in your original html if this entire section is contained in another element, then in the event delegation you can bind to that element instead of document.